# Dealing with nested dfs in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a df called datayrs2 here. Within it are more dfs (i.e datayrs2$data2006). There are 22 different dfs (data1999-2020) within datayrs2. I need to **First** split them up so they no longer have to be called by   `datayrs2$data2006` etc. and instead just data2006.

**Second** what is the easiest way to change the row names within every one. Each df has row names:

```
"proe_avg...99"              "outside_run_rate...100"    "inside_run_rate...101"      "yards_per_attempt...102" "yac_avg...103"              "qb_scramble_rate...104"
"qb_hit_rate...105"          "qb_sack_rate...106"
"first_down_pass_rate...107" "yards_over_sticks...108"
"int_avg...109"              "fumb_avg...110"
"penyd_avg...111"            "thrddnconv_avg...112"
```

with the "...#" on each is different and I can change each one individually with `gsub('[.0-9]*', '', rownames(datayrs2$data2006))` but I want to know how to construct maybe a for loop to make this easier than doing it 22 times.

Comment: `unnest_longer` and perhaps `hoist` of package {tidyr} might be a convenient way: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
list2env(lapply(datayrs2, function(x) {
  row.names(x) <- sub("\\.+\\d+$", "", row.names(x))
   x}), 
.GlobalEnv)
```